# django database performane separate tables vs GenericRelation

Tags: django, model, database-performance

I have 2 models, say A and B and the third is named order
.On side of database performance Which way is better (when the fields  of order is common)
one or two .

In other words, what are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

implementation one:

```
class A(models.Model):
   order=GenericRelation('Order')
   fields


class B(models.Model):
   order=GenericRelation('Order')
   fields


class Order(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

vs-----
implementation two:

```
class A(models.Model):
   fields

class B(models.Model):
   fields



class OrderA(models.Model):
    a=models.ForeignKey(A,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fields

class OrderB(models.Model):
    b=models.ForeignKey(B,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    same fields of orderA
```

Comment: Usually it is odd that you have an `OrderA` and `OrderB` model in the first place. Why do you want to separate these? This will usually result in *high coupling*, and *low cohesion*.

Comment: I think it will be easier to connect to them, so the database performance will be faster

Comment: what you describe looks like [*database sharding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_(database_architecture)) perhaps you should take a look for sharding solutions in Django.